# HTML5 responsive navigation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/K5ZH7/1/)

So when screen is > 580 px width, it needs to work on mouse hover, and it does.
If screen is < 580 px width, you have to click on a link for it to show sub links. 
For example, if you look at the [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/K5ZH7/1/)  and click on `portfolio` the sub menu's will open, but inside those subs there are other subs, for example work has two sub menu's -> internship and freelance. The problem is, in mobile view `portfolio` works with on click, but the sub menu's work on mouse hover, but they also need to be on click view and if you click somewhere else on the screen, they need to disappear.

In jQuery I have tested:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 580) { }
```

and

```
if (screen.width < 580) { }
```

and inside these I have the .click function, but it does not work?

Can someone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Just looking at the navigation makes my head hurt.  Have you thought of simplifying it?  EG The nav only shows top level and then have a page dedicated to project?  If I was on a mobile device, even the desktop, I wouldn't want to deal with a deep structure of menus and their child menus.

Comment: That is indeed better, but I have a lot of projects and I want to categorize it. But yes, I will look at it and simplify it and categorize it in another way on the project page itself, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript or jQuery. Use [CSS3 media quires](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) instead.